# PowerPivot calculate date difference in the current context

Tags: excel, powerpivot, data-analysis, dax

I'd like to segment my customers on their purchasing activity (active, sleeping, dead). To do so, I need to find the number of the days between the last purchase date and current context (because the customer can be sleeping in one period and active in another).

So I add the calculated field to the Customers table:

```
LastPurchaseDate:= LASTDATE(purchases[ClearDate])
```

and it works fine.

The problem occurs when I try to calculate the days difference between two days:

```
LastPurchaseDaysAgo:= CALCULATE(1*(TODAY()-[LastPurchaseDate]))
```

In the result I get the same value everywhere (customers in rows and date hierarchy in columns) and the other fields added to the pivot stop calculating.

1. How do I fix the problem with the same value for every row? I understand that when I'm using TODAY() for diff calculation, I should get the same value for each customer over all periods, but I also get the same value for all the customers.
2. What should I use instead of TODAY() to calc the difference for the current date context? I tried to use *Calendar[Datekey]* - my dates table, but PowerPivot didn't like it...

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check that ClearDate is a date not a datetime. If it is a datetime you can transform it in DAX into a date by `DATE(YEAR(myTable([ClearDate]),MONTH(myTable([ClearDate]),DAY(myTable([ClearDate]))`. Then you should be able to subtract it from TODAY() to get a numeric value.

Comment: To be clear, the Tabular engine has no separate Date type. It only knows Date/time, internally represented by a decimal number (can't recall if float or decimal) where the whole number portion represents the number of days since a reference date, and the decimal portion represents the time portion of a day. You can create a datetime field with the time portion set to midnight (all 0s past the decimal), but cannot set or transform a field to a date.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case: ClearDate in my table is a date, I calculate it from datetime with the formula: TRUNC(datetime-column, 0), i.e. I leave only the date portion.

Comment: Rory, the thing is that i'm already getting the numeric value,  but it's the *same* for every cell... May be I confused you saying that the values stop calculating, but I meant all the *other* fields stop, but the *LastPurchaseDaysAgo* has value and it's the same everywhere...

Comment: I would guess that the numeric value for TODAY() is being returned everywhere. What happens when you try the following?
=
TODAY ()
    - DATE ( YEAR ( myTable[ClearDate] ), MONTH ( myTable[ClearDate] ), DAY ( myTable[ClearDate] ) )